# Python: edit text file by tkinter input

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am using Python3. I'm trying to learn how to edit text files by changing the variables on the text file to a user input variables on GUI.
Here is my code:

```
self.input = TK.Entry(self.root)
self.input.pack()
with open('fl.txt', 'r') as f:
   lines = f.readlines()
   self.a = lines[0].strip()
   lines[0] = str(self.input)+'\n'
   out = open('fl.txt', 'w')
   out.writelines(lines)
```

I'm getting this error message:

```
  self.input = TK.Entry(self.root)
NameError: name 'TK' is not defined.
```

If I change "TK" to "Tk", then I get: `type object 'Tk' has no attribute 'Entry'`. Can someone please help? Also, how do I save my input variable so I can use it in methods?

Comment: Have you import Tkinter? How?

Comment: Yes. from tkinter import * also I used self.root = Tk() if that's helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use:

```
from tkinter import *
```

I think you should remove the TK and write:

```
        self.input = Entry(self.root)
```

Comment: Thanks! Now it gives me the input line, but I can't get my input to my text file. How do I save the input as a variable so I could use it with methods?

Comment: @AlexB. The `Entry` widget allows the user to enter one line of text. Try the `Text` widget instead to enter multiple lines of text.